# Django: how to translate whole page content efficiently

Tags: django, internationalization

I am using django i18n and I have succeeded in translating strings and variables in my html tempate with `{% trans "some string" %}`.

But I want to translate a whole page content and not only a few strings, and my question: what is the best way to do this.

I have tried with `{% blocktrans %} html content {% endblocktrans %}`, but this is a very inefficient way, especially when I want to manage the content later.

I thought about something like:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="/next/page/" />
<select name="language">
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
<option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Where you could refer the value to a copy of the translated content. But I do not want to have two html pages for the same, and I am currently using "django-localeurl"

I have also heard of "django-rosetta"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want translations for dynamic (CMS-like) text, you should take a look at [django-multilangual](http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual/), the basic i18n is more fitted for short static strings, not for long dynamic ones.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
In my special case I have long static content to translate (disclaimer). 
So I think there is no ohter way than to translate it just once in the appropiate django.po file.